# It seems that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+1}} - \frac 1 {\sqrt {n+2}}\right)$ converges but I can't prove it

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

When I write out a few terms in the series it is clear that the sum is telescoping towards $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ 
$\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} - \frac 1 {\sqrt 3} + \frac 1 {\sqrt 3} - \frac 1 {\sqrt 4} + \frac 1 {\sqrt 4} ...$

It is known that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ diverges, but I can't use that with the direct comparison test since it is always greater than $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+1}}$ and likewise $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+2}}$ although this wouldn't help me anyway.

I tried the nth term test but I got $0$, and for the ratio test if I try just with $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+1}}$ I get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt {n+2}} \cdot \frac {\sqrt {n+1}} 1 = 1$

This is inconclusive. Maybe if I can prove that $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+1}}$ and  $\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+2}}$ both diverge similarly so that when they are subtracted they cancel eachother out?

Comment: Write down the $n^{th}$ partial sum, then show that *that* sequence converges. `Maybe if I can prove that ... both diverge similarly so that when they are subtracted they cancel each other out?` No, that's a wrong and dangerous way to even think to think about it.

Comment: But doesn't that get me to where I started since there will just be a repeated sequence of $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$? Although I suppose you can show that the terms cancel out so if each partial sum converges than the whole converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial sum is $s_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+1}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so the series converges.

It is the telescoping which finishes the job.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac 1 {\sqrt {n+1}} - \frac 1 {\sqrt {n+2}}\sim\frac12\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}$$

Comment: How did you simplify it into that? I was able to get it into 1 fraction but not further. And then are you able to prove that it converges by the direct comparison test?!

Comment: In this case telescoping is the best way. Otherwise you can find the asymptotic term by Taylor’s series. Once you have it you can prove convergence by comparison test.

Comment: That is beautiful, good job